# Java2WS CXF tool and packages <=> namespaces relation

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have a problem with java2WS CXF Tool, my cproject is builded with Maven, i have two modules, one for expose the services and the other is for the client.

The structure of the module that exposes the services looks as follows:

```
- WS-Service
  - com.oz.types
    - PersonType.java
  - com.oz.dto
    - AddressDto.java
    - UserDto.java
    - PersonDto.java
  - com.oz.ws.sei
    - UserManager
  - com.oz.ws.sei.impl
    - UserManagerImpl
```

I run the generator task with ant, the problem is than the namespaces in the descriptor for the dto package are put in the same namespace that SEI, i.e. http://sei.ws.oz.com instead of http://dto.oz.com.

The real problem is when i generate other WSDL with diferent package that use the same dto's, because the client for both generate the follow:

```
- com.oz.ws.sei
    - PersonType.java
    - AddressDto.java
    - UserDto.java
    - PersonDto.java
    - UserManager.java
    - ......
 - com.oz.ws.sei2
    - PersonType.java
    - AddressDto.java
    - UserDto.java
    - PersonDto.java
    - SeiTwo.java
    - ......
```

As you can see, the dto's are repeated in both packages, i try define explicitly the namespace in the SEI with the @WebParam annotation:

@WebMethod
boolean updateUserInfo(
          @WebParam(name = "user", targetNamespace = "http://ws.oz.com/dto") UserDto user
          );

but the generated code only create a package and one util class named ObjectFactory and the DTO are still leaves in the same package.

How can say to generator tool that respect my packages??

Thanks for your time.